# Add libstagefright in my Android NDK Application

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, stagefright

I made some changes in `AOSP` code and compiled it. Now i want to Add created `libstagefright.so` in my Applicaton.

In `Android.mk` i'm adding as `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` compiled `libstagefright.so` library with path.

Here is it`

> ```
>    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
>    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>    LOCAL_MODULE := libstagefright  
>    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./Source/out/target/product/generic/system/lib/libstagefright.so
>    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
>
>    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
>    LOCAL_MODULE    := example
>    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := example.cpp
>    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog-landroid 
>    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libstagefright 
>    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```

When i'm building and running program I don't see any changes in library.What is the Problem that i don't see any changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using `libstagefright.so`? Usually, one would be employing `MediaPlayerService` to retrieve the `media` specific functionalities and work thereof. Adding this file as a _Source File_ will not help. Can you please show how you are employing the services of `libstagefright.so`?

Comment: @Ganesh ... I'm trying to do hardware decoding from NDK, But I need to check logs in `libstagefright.so` and add my own logs.

Comment: You can enable the logs, add your own logs in the source and rebuild the library. Please replace the library in your `system.img` or directly on the device at `/system/lib`. Wouldn't this solve your issue?

Comment: @Ganesh... for that i must have root access. right? 
Is there any solution besides this?

Comment: If you don't have root access, rebuild the system to create the new `system.img` and flash it on the system. Can't you simply root the system as you are trying to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `libstagefright.so`, you can build the AOSP-derived library as `libmybetterstagefrght.so` and use it in your app instead of `stagefright`. You can put your library in your `libs` folder just like any other library. You don't need root for that.

Note that the library you build will still connect to many OMX and other binaries in `/system/lib`, so all interfaces should be maintained. You probably want to start with the AOSP revision that corresponds to the system level of your device. You may face compatibility problems if the device uses a customized Android - for best results, take a Nexus device.